# Casting from pair<K,V>& to pair<const K,V>&

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, casting, standards

Is is correct by the standard to cast `std::pair<T1,T2>&` to `std::pair<const T1,T2>&` ?

I have some customized map object which holds its inner key-value pair as `std::pair<Key,Value>`.
I want to give to possibility to iterate over the map with an iterator,
with the possibility to change the value, but not the key.

trying to `static_cast` the type `pair<K,V>&` to `pair<const K,V>&` with VC++ fails.
I could do it with `reinterpret_cast` tricks, but I wonder if it is safe by the standard.
and if not, is there any possibility to expose `pair<K,V>&` as `pair<const K,V>&` that doesn't require re-write
the class ?